# TYPO3 Plugin: disable content output

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I want to create a plugin in TYPO3 10, that does not output anything to the frontend (The controller will add some header data). However I did not find a simple way to disable the output. Of course I could create an empty fluid template. But I would still have this left:

```html
<div id="c*" class="frame frame-default frame-type-list frame-layout-0"></div>
```

Now I could override the `List.html` Template from Fluid Styled Content, but this all seems like a bit much just to output nothing. Also overriding the FSC Template would affect other extensions as well. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Probably I could also do the same with a new content element instead of a plugin, but I like the way to load data from a repository with a plugin.

Comment: this sounds more like a property of a page. if editors should be able to set this 'header data' insert a field in the `pages` record. then build the header data from this field content.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this seems not to be the way you should do it... A frontend plugin is placed as a type of Content Element, but headers are no "normal" content.

Maybe one of these APIs can help you:

- [Canonical API](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/CanonicalApi/Index.html)
- [MetaTag API](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/MetaTagApi/Index.html)
- [PageTitle API](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/PageTitleApi/Index.html)

Or tell us a bit more details of what you wish to achieve. Which headers do you what to add?